# ng-repeat not iterating through json object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

The controller which contains the JSON object, which is then passed to the view.

```
'use strict';

//app global variable
//this is the controller that handles post requests
//declare services as dependecies $http, $location, custom service apiServiceWeb
app.controller('menteeMentorsCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $rootScope, $location, loggedInStatus, setCredentials, apiServiceWeb) {


  //get cookie, and then make api call
  var cookieData = setCredentials.getCookie('globals');

  console.log(cookieData);
  console.log("email " + cookieData.auth.username);
  console.log("userType " + cookieData.auth.userType);
  console.log("token " + cookieData.auth.token);

  var ctr_scope = $scope;
  $scope.users = []; //declare an empty array

  $scope.alert = {};
  $scope.showAlert = false;
  $scope.users = [{
    "activeMentors": [{
      "profession": "test",
      "lastName": "test",
      "jobTitle": "test",
      "chatIdentifier": "e46eacf0f7dbd998aba9957b127b51935cbd4fed68533d5708e22c632b60eaa4d65c81fc3cfe3192112c02db1ab4090bc0f18f8a8fdb8cd60f4368643a9a5dbd",
      "title": "",
      "pushToken": "tets",
      "token": {
        "secureToken": "c243fac3ee241f9cb7c442ec893a9c58d85312b890af8719949057e61c3d6a7670455e178a692f27ae0e07da89b4b5d6b0d4267df799249969c70a829cbbab9d"
      },
      "mentees": [],
      "firstName": "test",
      "profileColour": "test",
      "emailAddress": "test",
      "termsAgreed": test,
      "ambition": {
        "ambition": "test",
        "isPrivate": "test"
      },
      "dob": "21/04/1991",
      "busy": test,
      "describingWords": [
        "tese",
        "test",
        "",
        "",
        ""
      ],
      "userType": "mentor",
      "id": {
        "machineIdentifier": 12374093,
        "processIdentifier": 7963,
        "counter": 705715,
        "timestamp": 1439803213
      },
      "requestedMentees": [],
      "profileImageUrl": "test"
    }],
    "requestedMentors": [{
      "profession": "test",
      "lastName": "test",
      "jobTitle": "test",
      "title": "test",
      "mentees": [],
      "firstName": "test",
      "emailAddress": "test",
      "termsAgreed": false,
      "ambition": {
        "ambition": "",
        "isPrivate": "TRUE"
      },
      "dob": "20/06/80",
      "busy": false,
      "describingWords": [
        "Compassionate",
        "Independent",
        "Passionate",
        "Inquisitive",
        "Creative"
      ],
      "userType": "tets",
      "id": {
        "machineIdentifier": 12374093,
        "processIdentifier": 7963,
        "counter": 705580,
        "timestamp": 1439775250
      },
      "requestedMentees": [],
      "profileImageUrl": "test"
    }]
  }];

});
```

View:

This is where I use ng-repeat.

```
 <div role="main" class="container theme-showcase">
      <div class="" style="margin-top:90px;">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2 id="tables">list items</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="menteeMentorsCtrl">
                <div class="alert alert-info" ng-hide=true>
                    <p>Sort key: {{sortKey}}</p>
                    <p>Reverse: {{reverse}}</p>
                    <p>Search String : {{search}}</p>
                </div>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Search</label>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>

<div ng-repeat="test in users.requestedMentors">
 <span>Name : {{ test.firstName }}</span>
 <span>Age : {{ test.lastName }}</span>
</div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

There are two parent objects in the json object, when I do test in users.requestedMentors , nothing is returned, why is this happening, thanks.

Comment: Any error in the console

Comment: It would be useful if you created a snippet with your code that people can run using the [stack overflow code snippets feature](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or alternatively https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: nope, there isnt any.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
<div ng-repeat="test in users[0]['requestedMentors']">
 <span>Name : {{ test.firstName }}</span>
 <span>Age : {{ test.lastName }}</span>
</div>
```

**Explaination**

This is because `users` is itself an `array of objects` and you are trying to acccess the first element of it.

**Update**

If there are multiple `objects` in the `users` array you should use `ng-repeat`

Eg:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div ng-repeat="test in user['requestedMentors']">
     <span>Name : {{ test.firstName }}</span>
     <span>Age : {{ test.lastName }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or users[0].requestedMentors because your users is an array containing only 1 object

Comment: Thanks, sorry quite new to angular so getting used to the syntax.

Comment: @user3754111 : Welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, users is an array object. Before accessing the each object inside the user array, you need to loop over the users object first. you should have something like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
<div ng-repeat="test in user.requestedMentors">
  <span>Name : {{ test.firstName }}</span>
  <span>Age : {{ test.lastName }}</span>
</div>
```